# Check one column based on other column

Tags: excel

Say I have two columns like this:

```
A   B
=======
3  TEXT
4   8
7  TEXT
```

What would be a formula to apply conditional formatting on a cell in colA where the cell in colB equals "TEXT"?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(B4="TEXT", A4,"")
```

Assuming that 3 is in A4 and TEXT is in B4 then this calculation is in C4 (copied down for the rest of the cells)

Comment: hi @Anthony i have try your answer but seems not work. is there any links that i can kearn this case?thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=B1="TEXT"
```

as a Conditional Formatting formula rule applied to A:A.